# accessing dll files in Java

Tags: java, matlab, dll

I have a  DLL file which has been used in Matlab for SVM classification. I want to use it in Java. I have loaded the DLL file and created the interface as mentioned here -http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/

```
public interface mex_smo_train_test extends FunctionMapper {        
}
```

But how do I access the functions written there? I saw examples in wikipedia but in my case I don't know what code/functions/variables are there in the dll file so I am not sure what to declare in the interface. (I have training data, class labels and Kernel Parameters exactly like it is in Matlab)
Matlab code calls the DLL with the code below -

```
     msvm{k} = mex_smo_train_test(X, biny, [], T);
```

Is there any way to call dll file from Java like it has been done in matlab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna) (JNA) library on GitHub. The [Getting Starte](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md)d page should give you what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I edited my code - public interface mex_smo_train_test extends FunctionMapper {
  mex_smo_train_test INSTANCE = (mex_smo_train_test)Native.loadLibrary("mex_smo_train_test",mex_smo_train_test.class);
 } but I am still confused on how to access the methods inside the dll file since when I call getFunctionName I have to add my own methods.